# Intro layout problems with weight

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating an intro activity and What I want is that logo was double bigger than text, and the text was centered to the layout.

With the next code I am having problems with diferents layouts (in some screens the `TextView` is not shown:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_intro"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_view_desc"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/iconok" />
    </LinearLayout> 

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textSize="55sp"
            android:text="@string/loading_text3" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You want your logo width to be double your text width right? cause some answers is for height!

Comment: Post image of your desired layout

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Should the `TextView`be centered vertically or horizontally, or both? Should the `ImageView` have double height or double width of `TextView`? `TextView` below the `ImageView` or next to it? Should the image Please rephrase your question.

Comment: @MarcForn can you plz attach rough sketch of your layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question and comments, I think below snippet will help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_intro"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="66"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email_textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="55sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

test this code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1.0" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:layout_weight="0.66" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_intro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_view_desc"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.34" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="55sp"
        android:text="@string/loading_text3" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But I don't want to scroll interaction. I just want that 66% of the layout was the image centered and the 33% left the textview centered.

Comment: image centered in the top layout. right? not centered in the hall window.

Answer (score 1):

(After your comment) then you should set first inner linear layout's weight 2, and second's 1. Also use `layout_height =" 0"` for them.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_intro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_view_desc"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/iconok" />
</LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="55sp"
        android:text="@string/loading_text3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_intro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@stringimage_view_desc"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/image_view_desc" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="55sp"
            android:text="@stringloading_text3" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and change `margin` according to your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="3" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_intro"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="abcd"
        android:textSize="55sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```